# C# Combo box value change, what Event should I use to write update the registry?

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a read only combo-box with 5 values in, when the user selects a new value what event should I use to write that value to the registry?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well regardless of what you will end up doing with the value when selected, it is safe to use the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event.

Here is a little follow up info on this event vs the other commonly used events. (from MSDN)

> SelectionChangeCommitted is raised
>   only when the user changes the combo
>   box selection. Do not use
>   SelectedIndexChanged or
>   SelectedValueChanged to capture user
>   changes, because those events are also
>   raised when the selection changes
>   programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to check when a user selects a value in a combobox

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this event. **"SelectionChangeCommitted"**

private void ChangedCommitted_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
enter code here
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

How about if you are using the DateTimePicker? This does not have the SelectionChangeCommitted value.